# Integrate face detection through Carthage gives error

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-mlkit

The Face detection SDK of firebase does not support Carthage installation. Whenever I am trying to integrate the firebase SDK through Carthage application crashes giving the error:

> GTMSessionFetcher library not loaded in the bundle.

I have gone through the git documentation and other sites too where the firebase team said Carthage support is experimental.

Does anyone have a solution over it?

**Note**: I want to integrate it through Carthage only.

Comment: Make sure the instructions at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md are exactly followed ...

Comment: I have followed all the steps. But still the issue is not resolved. I also get to know that I need to develop a framework as static because the firebase frameworks are developed as static. Doing the same is not loading the resource of the framework.

Comment: Like after creating the framework as static then bundle not return framework path it only return me the local path of a project where I included my framework.